# JavaScript: "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls".

Tags: javascript

Every time I run IE for seeing a javascript program, it says " Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls " and a button " Allow blocked content ". When I click it the problem is fixed, but I should do this every time. 
Does anybody know how I can fix it forever on - Internet Explorer - ?

Comment: Go through the Internet Options, and check the security settings for the zone. And btw., not a programming question, and off-topic for SO.

Comment: Yes, completely off-topic.

Comment: Just as information. In our case the warning was because an image element in HTML that referenced an image in the file system, like:
<img src="file:///C:/images/img.gif"></img>
Regarding the suggestions below (like "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer") I do not consider these ones as solutions. Simply loosing the security settings only hides the problem, but might cause even more serious issues.

Comment: @CBroe - I disagree it is off topic. I have added "(on my computer)" to the question (pending approval) because of course javascript is NOT generically blocked by IE, but it IS BLOCKED if the file is from your computer. And the reason it's a programming question is because IE11 painfully blocks all scripts in this circumstance, and the only reason I can see that Amin would want that is to test his Javascript (which he implies). Besides, I was having this problem and this was at top of Google's finds.

Answer (score 5):

1) Open Internet Explorer.

2) On the Tools menu select Internet Options.

3) Select the Advanced tab.

4) Scroll down to find the Security option.

5) Check the checkbox " Allow active content to run in files on My Computer ".

Comment: I don't want to downvote your answer, but I do not consider this one as solution. Simply loosing the security settings only hides the problem, but might cause even more serious issues. Find the real reason of the warning and fix that.

Comment: @pholpar There is no rational reason. It blocks even `console.log("test");` IE is just the most terrible browser in the world!

Comment: @pholpar I have added "(on my computer)" to the question (pending approval) because of course javascript is NOT generically blocked by IE, but it IS BLOCKED if the file is from your computer. And it is a setting that is extremely hard to find as it is not under the security tab, and indeed, changing security is unwise. To make it easier to find, I edited this answer and added "(not Security tab)" to item 3 and "(In IE11, you will find that in the lowest "Security" section, 2nd item from top of that section)" at end. (I'm putting this in the comment in case edits are not approved).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/internet-explorer-has-blocked-an-active-x-control/fe6ecb9d-5a39-4253-a553-352058a5a841

> Step 1: To troubleshoot the active X pop issue, follow the steps and
>   check if it helps:
>
> a)      Open Internet Explorer.
>
> b)      Click on Tools menu and select Internet Options.
>
> c)       Under Security tab click on Custom level.
>
> d)      Scroll down to the ActiveX controls and plug-ins group, and
>   ensure that all ActiveX options are set to either “Enable” or
>   “Prompt”. Since the remote viewing software is published in an
>   unsigned state, please make certain that the options “Download
>   unsigned ActiveX controls” and “Initialize and Script ActiveX controls
>   not marked as safe” are set to “Prompt”