# IE blocks my own js code, but not on big websites

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a webpage file (page.html) and I use javascript to make it work. I have these two sources of js / jquery in my header tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> ... my custom js functions ... </script>
```

When I open that html page in IE11, I get this message:

**Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls.**

I never see that message when I visit big websites like e.g. pubmed (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/). But when I right-click and hit "Q" to observe the source code of pubmed, I see that there are `<script>` tags too. Why does my own js get blocked?

Comment: Are you running a local web server? If not you have to use a custom security level to run scripts in IE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically allow blocked content in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038724/how-to-automatically-allow-blocked-content-in-ie)

Comment: I just right click the html file and click on "open with internet explorer". no web server involved, just a plain html file

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx could help

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. On the Tools menu select Internet Options.
3. Select the Advanced tab.
4. Scroll down to find the Security option.
5. Check the checkbox " Allow active content to run in files on My Computer ".
   source:
   [JavaScript: "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673513/javascript-internet-explorer-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-a)
   and it is working for me