# data-role="tagsinput" working in crome and edge but not in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, input, bootstrap-tags-input

I am designing a site using Bootstrap. TagsInput is working in Chrome and Edge but not in Internet Explorer.
The tag boxes are not appearing in Internet Explorer
Attaching the code below:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="author" content="" />
            <title>TNL metadata tagging</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
            <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="row row-cols-1">
                  <div class="col mt-3"><b>Category</b></div>
                  <div class="col mt-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" value="News" data-role="tagsinput" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input").val()
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Screenshots:-
[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05o7M.png)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeURv.png)

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with the code you provided but failed. I added the resource files for bootstrap 3.3.7 and bootstrap 1.8.3 to the project path, and it works fine in Chrome,Edge and IE11 as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc2it.png). If possible, could you provide more details, for example what version of IE are you using, the version of the bootstrap/bootstrap-tagsinput resource or something?

Comment: @XudongPeng, Actually on IE I am getting this error message "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX Controls" which I can bypass by clicking on "Allow Blocked Content" but Inside my internal application which uses IE I will not get any pop-up...I need to bypass this error through my code only. IE Version used here:-1909.

Comment: If this is the case, You can try to modify some settings in Internet options. Just refer to this case: [JavaScript: "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673513/javascript-internet-explorer-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-a).